# python look for a specific string in a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am relatively new to python and I tried to work with beautifulSoup to download some contents of a website which tracks gas prices.
On the website you can list the cheapest gas stations around your address with a radius and the sort of gasoline. So far this was straight forward for me since the search parameters are displayed in the url.
When it comes to check the price for the gas stations I run into a problem where I need help.

On the website each gas station is an own object which is identified by a certain string. Now here comes the problem for me. I don't know how to access the object by searching for this particular string.

I tried this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

city = 'Stuttgart'
radius = 5
diesel = 3
Super_e10 = 5
Super_e5 = 7
Superplus = 6
PremiumDiesel = 12

url = f'https://www.clever-tanken.de/tankstelle_liste?lat=&lon=&ort={city}&spritsorte={diesel}&     
r={radius}'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

when I print soup the gas stations are displayed like this

`<a href="/tankstelle_details/50109" onmouseover="generateDygraph(event, '50109', 'hover', 'Freie Tankstelle', 'Salzburger Str.  46-56' )">`

however the gas stations are identified by the link /tankstelle_details/50109 where I am having trouble to get this part out of the soup.

I tried

```
 if "/tankstelle_details/" in (soup):
     print('true')
```

or

```
gas_station = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href':'"/tankstelle_details/9996"'})
print(gas_station)
```

but everytime the programm returns nothing.

Comment: this is one of the most common issues i see with web-scraping: searching for something that isn't present in the results. if we know more about why you expect that result in the page, we might be able to help further.

Comment: try if "/tankstelle_details/" in soup: (no paranthesis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

Following line will only `find_all()` links that´s attribute href matches exactly the string, problem in your example is no such href that ends with `9996`:

```
soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href':'"/tankstelle_details/9996"'})
```

Checking if string is in soup is missing the *str* in front of (soup):

```
if "/tankstelle_details/" in (soup):
     print('true')
```

#### How to fix?

**Option #1**

Selecting all the `<a>` that contains */tankstelle_details/* in its href you can use `css selectors` - In my opinion it is much easier/felxible as the `find()` / `find_all()` methods.

```
soup.select('[href*="/tankstelle_details/"]')
```

**Option #2**

You can also achieve this with `find_all()` but you have to import `re` module and use it with `compile()` in your selection:

```
import re
soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'/tankstelle_details/'))
```

---

Not sure how the expected result should look like, but with `stripped_strings` you will get some structured data:

```
list(a.stripped_strings)
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

city = 'Stuttgart'
radius = 5
diesel = 3
Super_e10 = 5
Super_e5 = 7
Superplus = 6
PremiumDiesel = 12

url = f'https://www.clever-tanken.de/tankstelle_liste?lat=&lon=&ort={city}&spritsorte={diesel}&r={radius}'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('[href*="/tankstelle_details/"]'):
    print(list(a.stripped_strings))
```

#### Output

```
['1.48', '9', 'geändert', 'Heute', 'vor 44 Min.', 'Preis von', 'MTS-K', 'SB', '1.8 km', 'Hackstr. 6', '70190 Stuttgart']
['1.48', '9', 'geändert', 'Heute', 'vor 14 Min.', 'Preis von', 'MTS-K', 'AVIA Xpress', '2.2 km', 'Klingenstr. 123', '70188 Stuttgart']
['1.48', '9', 'geändert', 'Heute', 'vor 42 Min.', 'Preis von', 'MTS-K', 'RAN', '5.1 km', 'Hedelfinger Str. 17', '70327 Stuttgart']
['1.48', '9', 'geändert', 'Heute', 'vor 14 Min.', 'Preis von', 'MTS-K', 'AVIA Xpress Automatentankstell', '3.6 km', 'Neckarwiesenstr. 7', '70188 Stuttgart']
['1.49', '9', 'geändert', 'Heute', 'vor 26 Min.', 'Preis von', 'MTS-K', 'TotalEnergies', '3.7 km', 'Ulmer Str. 206', '70188 Stuttgart']
['1.49', '9', 'geändert', 'Heute', 'vor 24 Min.', 'Preis von', 'MTS-K', 'Shell', '2.3 km', 'Talstr. 28', '70188 Stuttgart']
['1.50', '9', 'geändert', 'Heute', 'vor 0 Sek.', 'Preis von', 'MTS-K', 'OMV', '3.9 km', 'Epplestr. 55', '70597 Stuttgart']

...
```

Comment: thank you very much. Your Answer solved the issue much better than I had hoped :)